# Angular updating ng-show / ng-hide after API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm new to Angular and still trying to understand how it all works and best practices.  My app is a single page Rails application utilizing Angular.

I'm working on a piece where a user can follow / unfollow another user.  Based on the way the back-end is structured (using Mongo), followers are embedded in the user model.

What I'd like to have happen is when a user clicks follow, it posts an API call to follow the user, and then the button changes from 'follow' to 'unfollow'.  I've got the follow and unfollow piece working with the API, just don't know how to toggle the button from follow to unfollow and back when toggled.

Since the data is pulled to build the profile page from the User model, and the follow / unfollow is not happening on the User model, I'm guessing that's why the bindings aren't working automatically.  I have worked it out by incrementing / decrementing the follower count and adding the user to the followers by pushing it onto the array.

Just need help with the best practice for toggling the button here.  Open to any other refactoring here too.

Here's what I got so far...

**users_controller:**

```
recipe.controller "UsersCtrl", ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'User', 'Follower', ($scope, $routeParams, User, Follower) ->
  $scope.breadcrumb = $routeParams.id
  $scope.current_user_name = window.current_user_name
  $scope.user = User.get({id: $routeParams.id})
  $scope.addFollower = ->
    newFollower = new Follower({user_id: $scope.current_user_name, follower_id: $routeParams.id})
    newFollower.$save() # Add success / failure 
    $scope.user.followers.push({username: $scope.current_user_name})
    $scope.user.follower_count += 1
  $scope.removeFollower = ->
    removeFollower = new Follower({user_id: $scope.current_user_name, follower_id: $routeParams.id})
    removeFollower.$delete()
    $scope.user.follower_count -= 1

  $scope.myProfile = ->
    if $scope.current_user_name == $routeParams.id
      return true
    else
      return false
  $scope.followsUser = ->
    in_followers($scope.user.followers, $scope.current_user_name)

  in_followers = (array, username) ->
    i = 0  
    while i < array.length
      return (array[i].username is username)
      i++
    false
]
```

**profile.html.haml**

```
%button{"ng-click" => "addFollower()", "ng-hide" => "myProfile(); followsUser()", :class => "btn btn-primary"} FOLLOW
%button{"ng-click" => "removeFollower()", "ng-show" => "followsUser()", "ng-hide" => "myProfile()", :class => "btn btn-primary"} UNFOLLOW
```

**follower.js.coffee**

```
 recipe.factory 'Follower', ['$resource', ($resource) ->
  Follower = $resource("/api/users/:user_id/follows", {user_id: "@user_id", follower_id: "@follower_id"}, 
    delete: {method: "DELETE", url: "/api/users/:user_id/follows/:follower_id", params: {user_id: "@user_id", follower_id: "@follower_id"}})
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you will need to add a value for isFollowing and keep that updated, then from your UI/markup you can do one of a few things, here are two:

with two buttons, toggling visibility

```
<button ng-show="isFollowing" ng-click="removeFollower()">Unfollow</button>
<button ng-hide="isFollowing" ng-click="addFollower()">Follow</button>
```

or you could use one button changing the text of the button, and expose a new function named setFollower which will call either addFollower or removeFollower internally

```
<button ng-click="setFollower()">{{ isFollowing ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow' }}</button>
```

Comment: thanks.  This was very helpful.  Especially the part about how to implement the single button.  I hadn't thought of that!